# Select running balance from table credit debit columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, cumulative-sum

I have a SQL Server 2008 table, and I need to select a running balance from it

```
TransDate    Credit    Debit    Datasource
------------------------------------------
2014-01-01   5000      NULL     3
2014-01-07   NULL      2000     3
2014-01-11   5000      NULL     3
2014-02-03   6000      NULL     4
2014-02-06   NULL      4000     4
2014-02-11   3000      NULL     4
2014-02-21   NULL      1000     3
2014-02-28   2000      NULL     3
2014-03-01   5000      NULL     3
```

I tried a correlated query

```
Select 
    t.TransDate, 
    t.Credit, 
    t.Debit, 
    (Select sum(coalesce(x.credit, 0) - coalesce(x.debit, 0))  
    From Transactions x 
    WHERE x.DataSource IN (3,4)  AND (x.TransDate >= '2014/02/01' AND x.TransDate <= '2014/02/28' ) 
    AND x.TransDate = t.TransDate) Balance
From 
    Transactions t
```

but I get all nulls for the `Balance`.

Expected output is

```
TransDate    Credit    Debit     Balance
------------------------------------------
2014-01-11   NULL      NULL      8000      <- opening balance     
2014-02-03   6000      NULL      14000
2014-02-06   NULL      4000      10000
2014-02-11   3000      NULL      13000
2014-02-21   NULL      1000      12000
2014-02-28   2000      NULL      15000     <- closing balance
```

Comment: From where did you get Balance `8000`? Could you provide SQL Fiddle?

Comment: the 8000 is the balance of the previous month, the expected result posted   is for `'2014/02/01' AND  '2014/02/28'`

Comment: @Smith check my answer. Added  SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bdf6/6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to self join table.

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  TransDate DATE,
  Credit INT,
  Debit INT,
);
INSERT INTO Test VALUES
('2014-01-01',   5000,      NULL),  
('2014-01-07',   NULL,      2000),   
('2014-01-11',   5000,      NULL),   
('2014-02-03',   6000,      NULL),    
('2014-02-06',   NULL,      4000),    
('2014-02-11',   3000,      NULL),   
('2014-02-21',   NULL,      1000),     
('2014-02-28',   2000,      NULL),     
('2014-03-01',   5000,      NULL) 

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT t2.TransDate, 
       t2.Credit, 
       t2.Debit, 
       SUM(COALESCE(t1.credit, 0) - COALESCE(t1.debit, 0)) AS Balance
FROM Test t1 
INNER JOIN Test t2
    ON t1.TransDate <= t2.TransDate
WHERE t1.DataSource IN (3,4)  
GROUP BY t2.TransDate, t2.Credit, t2.Debit
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE (TransDate >= '2014/01/11' AND TransDate <= '2014/02/28' )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TransDate   Credit  Debit   Balance
2014-01-11  5000    (null)  8000
2014-02-03  6000    (null)  14000
2014-02-06  (null)  4000    10000
2014-02-11  3000    (null)  13000
2014-02-21  (null)  1000    12000
2014-02-28  2000    (null)  14000
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bdf6/33)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the opening balance is suppose to be 8000, not 11000 and the other balances does not correspond to mine posted in the question

Comment: @Smith Provide me what is `DataSource`. I see only 3 columns in `Transaction`  table `TransDate    Credit    Debit`

Comment: Please see the question again

Comment: i need to sharpen my sql query writing, which book or resource can i use. which ones did you use or can you recommend??

Comment: I've read this book: `Training Kit Exam 70-461 Querying MS SQL Server 2012`, very detailed explained.

Comment: What if there are multiple transactions on the same date?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas Can Any body able to advice/help the same question asked by Smith above can be achievable through lead / lag function in sql server 2017... How

Comment: anyone has the solution to this same problem in oracle ?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to doing this:

### Data Set

```
CREATE TABLE Test1(
  Id int,
  TransDate DATE,
  Credit INT,
  Debit INT
);

INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES
(1, '2014-01-01',   5000,      NULL),  
(2, '2014-01-07',   NULL,      2000),   
(3, '2014-01-11',   5000,      NULL),   
(4, '2014-02-03',   6000,      NULL),    
(5, '2014-02-06',   NULL,      4000),    
(6, '2014-02-11',   3000,      NULL),   
(7, '2014-02-21',   NULL,      1000),     
(8, '2014-02-28',   2000,      NULL),     
(9, '2014-03-01',   5000,      NULL)
```

### Solution

```
SELECT  TransDate,
        Credit, 
        Debit, 
        SUM(isnull(Credit,0) - isnull(Debit,0)) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Balance
FROM Test1
order by TransDate
```

### OUTPUT

```
TransDate   Credit  Debit   Balance
2014-01-01  5000    NULL    5000
2014-01-07  NULL    2000    3000
2014-01-11  5000    NULL    8000
2014-02-03  6000    NULL    14000
2014-02-06  NULL    4000    10000
2014-02-11  3000    NULL    13000
2014-02-21  NULL    1000    12000
2014-02-28  2000    NULL    14000
2014-03-01  5000    NULL    19000
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select 
    x.TransDate, 
    x.Credit, 
    x.Debit, 
    SUM(coalesce(y.credit, 0) - coalesce(y.debit, 0))  AS Balance
FROM Transactions x 
INNER JOIN Transasctions y
    ON y.TransDate <= x.TransDate
    AND Y.DataSource IN (3,4)  
WHERE x.DataSource IN (3,4)  
GROUP BY
    x.TransDate, 
    x.Credit, 
    x.Debit
```

Note that, for large datasets this can get bad real quick... might want to use a cursor or try new 'Windowing' functions.

More here: https://brettwgreen.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/sql-cursors-are-slow-except-when-they-arent/

Comment: i get an error `The multi-part identifier "t.TransDate" could not be bound.`, can figure out why

Comment: Fixed the aliases.. try my revised answer

Comment: the query correct, but it return all result without date ranges, i notices you omitted the dates in the answer you just midified?

Comment: You can add them back if you want... just depends on what you want to do. The join to Transctions y is not date restricted so it should still give you the correct answer.

Comment: May also need to filter Y on the DataSource also... depends on what's in the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Following Worked With Me:

```
WITH tempDebitCredit AS (
Select 0 As Details_ID, null As Creation_Date, null As Reference_ID, 'Brought Forward' As Transaction_Kind, null As Amount_Debit, null As Amount_Credit, isNull(Sum(Amount_Debit - Amount_Credit), 0) 'diff'
From _YourTable_Name
where Account_ID = @Account_ID
And Creation_Date < @Query_Start_Date
Union All
SELECT a.Details_ID, a.Creation_Date, a.Reference_ID, a.Transaction_Kind, a.Amount_Debit, a.Amount_Credit, a.Amount_Debit - a.Amount_Credit 'diff'
FROM _YourTable_Name a
where Account_ID = @Account_ID
And Creation_Date >= @Query_Start_Date And Creation_Date <= @Query_End_Date
)

SELECT a.Details_ID, a.Creation_Date, a.Reference_ID, a.Transaction_Kind, 
a.Amount_Debit, a.Amount_Credit, SUM(b.diff) 'Balance'
FROM   tempDebitCredit a, tempDebitCredit b
WHERE b.Details_ID <= a.Details_ID
GROUP BY a.Details_ID, a.Creation_Date, a.Reference_ID, a.Transaction_Kind, 
a.Amount_Debit, a.Amount_Credit
Order By a.Details_ID Desc
```

Tested on Microsoft SQL Server