# Adding previous row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the Balance in below mentioned format. Balance+Balance(Row-1) I'm not sure if this explains well but adding previous rows Balance value to the current one and so on...

```
declare @tab table(Debit int,Credit int)

insert into @tab
select 1000  ,   NULL
union all   
select 2200   ,  NULL  
union all 
select NULL  ,   3000  
union all 
select 1500  ,   1500   


SELECT Debit, Credit, COALESCE(SUM(Credit), SUM(Debit)) AS Balance
FROM @tab
GROUP BY Debit, Credit
```

This is what I'm getting so far.

```
Debit    Credit     Balance
------------------------------
1000     NULL       1000
2200     NULL       2200
NULL     3000       3000
1500     1500       1500
```

This is what I'm looking for but please don't make that too complex to understand.

```
Debit    Credit     Balance
------------------------------
1000     NULL       1000
2200     NULL       3200
NULL     3000       6200
1500     1500       7700
```

Comment: You can't do this without a column providing order to the transactions.

Comment: Also, this is very similar [to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376584/applying-or-condition-on-sum-function-in-sql-server).  Rather than asking so many questions, just try asking one which covers everything.

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen This is similar to my previous one but I later realized that I need this thing too but couldn't ask that before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select running balance from table credit debit columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609750/select-running-balance-from-table-credit-debit-columns)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
   SELECT Debit, Credit, CAST(ISNULL(Debit,Credit) AS int) AS Balance 
   FROM Table1 

), cteRanked AS
(
   SELECT Debit, Credit, Balance, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
   FROM cte
) 
SELECT Debit, Credit,
(
  SELECT SUM(Balance) FROM cteRanked c2 WHERE c2.rownum <= c1.rownum
) AS Balance
FROM cteRanked c1;
```

Output

```
Debit   Credit  Balance
1000    (null)  1000
2200    (null)  3200
(null)  3000    6200
1500    1500    7700
```

Check Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/978a4/2

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `GROUP BY` clause just use *window function*

```
SELECT Debit, Credit, 
            SUM(COALESCE(Credit, Debit)) OVER (ORDER BY <identity col> 
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Balance
FROM @tab
```

Comment: The sum you are taking makes no sense, and without an explicit column for ordering, the order your query would generate also makes no sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen.. k. So, let we assumes o/p has some kind of `identity` coliumns.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to doing this:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE(id int, Debit int,Credit int)

INSERT INTO @tab (id, Debit, Credit)
VALUES  (1, 1000, NULL),
        (2, 2200, NULL),
        (3, NULL, 3000), 
        (4, 1500, 1500) 

SELECT  Debit, 
        Credit, 
        SUM(COALESCE(Credit, Debit)) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Balance
FROM @tab
```

Or additionally if you Need manage account balance, you can use this.

```
SELECT  Debit, 
        Credit, 
        SUM((isnull(Credit,0) - isnull(Debit,0))) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Balance
FROM @tab
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    declare @tab table(id int ,Debit int,Credit int)

    insert into @tab
    select 1, 1000  ,   NULL
    union all   
    select 2, 2200   ,  NULL  
    union all 
    select 3,NULL  ,   3000  
    union all 
    select 4, 1500  ,   1500   


    SELECT *,
    SUM(ISNULL(Debit,credit)) OVER(order by id ROWS UNBOUNDED  PRECEDING) 
    from @tab
```